# Process 32 bit binary string, with leading zeroes, in Excel application

Tags: excel, vba, string, binary

At cell A1, I have a string "01000000 01xx0000 000000x1 000xx000" where x can be 0 or 1 (note that it has space every 8 bits)
At cell A2, I have a string 0101 (or 1111)
At cell A3, I need to replace every "x" in A1 string by corresponding digit of A2 string.

Therefore A3 contains formula: = Substitute_pair(A1, "x", A2)

That means:
 - First "x" occurrence will be replaced by "0"
 - Second "x" occurrence will be replaced by "1"
 - Third "x" occurrence will be replaced by "0"
 - Fourth "x" occurrence will be replaced by "1"

```
The original string is          "01000000 01xx0000 000000x1 000xx000"
The output/expected string is:  "01000000 010x0000 00000011 00001000"
```

Below VBA script works in the VBA Debug window but with the Excel application, cell A3 always returns 0.

```
Public Function Substitute_pair(str As String, old_str As String, new_str As String) As Byte
    Dim str_origin As String
    For i = 1 To Len(new_str)
        tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(str, old_str, Mid(new_str, i, 1), 1)
        Debug.Print "Replacing " & i & " occurence " & old_str & " with value " & Mid(new_str, i, 1)
        str = tmp
    Next i
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = Substitute_pair("01000000 01xx0000 000000x1 000xx000", "x", "11111")
End Sub
```

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zero's.  `007` is the same as `7` therefore if the data is stored as a number there is no reason to store one leading zero, or a million.  However, numbers can also be stored as **`Text`** which you can add a mix of whatever characters you want.  Change the number formatting to text by selecting the cell(s) and hitting CTRL+1 and choosing 'Text' on the Number Format tab.

Comment: Thanks  ashleedawg. If I format cell A3 as "Text", the formula inside this cell cannot be conducted- so i cannot use the vba function i wrote above. I updated a bit my situation above with formula at cell A3 to clarify my issue

In general, I need to show the result in 32 bit as input string then perform some convert them to hex. 
For example 01000000 01110000 00000011 00011000 will have to be 
                         40              70            03             18